# SAS, delete multiple dataset

Tags: sas

If I have dataset AA1, AA2, AA3, AA4,...AA100 how do I delete all of them? I tried

```
proc sql; 
drop table AA1-AA100;
quit;
```

It didn't work. I do not want to use kill because I do not want to delete all dataset in that lib. Is there a better way to do it instead of using loop?

Answer (score 4):

Use `proc datasets` instead, this accepts `AA1-AA100` syntax, or the colon wildcard operator (e.g. `AA:` to delete all datsets beginning `AA`).

```
proc datasets lib=work;
delete aa1-aa10 ;
quit;
```

Comment: The colon was actually going to be my suggestion, but did not work with the proc sql drop...good to know that proc datasets supports it!!!! Awesome!